# range of last 10 numbers/frames in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing, matlab-cvst

I need to retrieve/register/remember last 10 frames from the video file. This is a small version of a bigger project for detecting micro-expressions. Therefore it need to check if "lines" have been showing for last 10 frames (detected) or if it is showing for more than 10 then it not detected. I'm also enforced to work with `vision.VideoFileReader` and `vision.OpticalFlow`. How to do this?

```
file = 'MEXTest.mp4';
vid = vision.VideoFileReader(file,'ImageColorSpace','RGB','VideoOutputDataType','single');
optFlo = vision.OpticalFlow('OutputValue','Horizontal and vertical components in complex form','ReferenceFrameDelay',3);
shapeInsertOptFloColor = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape','Lines','BorderColor','Custom','CustomBorderColor',[255 255 0]);

numFrames = 0;
frameList = {};
hasLines = zeros(10, 1, 'logical');

figH = figure;

while ~isDone(vid)
    colorFrame  = step(vid);
    colorFrameRes = imresize(colorFrame,0.3);
    grayFrame = rgb2gray(colorFrameRes);

    optFloVectors = step(optFlo, grayFrame);
    lines = oflo(optFloVectors,20);
    motionVectors = step(shapeInsertOptFloColor, colorFrameRes, lines);
    imshow(motionVectors); title('Optical Flow on Frame');

    notEmpty = ~isempty(lines);
    if numel(notEmpty) ~= 1, notEmpty = 1; end

    hasLines = [hasLines(2:end); notEmpty];

    if numFrames >= 10
        frameList = [frameList(2:end) colorFrame];
    else
        frameList = [frameList colorFrame];
    end

    numFrames = numFrames + 1;

    if numFrames >= 10 && all(hasLines)
        disp('Micro-Expression Detected')
    else
        disp('Not detected')
    end

    if ~ishghandle(figH)
        close all
        break
    end
end
release(vid);
```

Comment: So what exactly are you asking?  Do you want to remember the last 10 frames of the video that were read in before the current point?

Comment: `isempty(points) == false` -> `~isempty(points)`

Comment: yes, sorry for not expressing this correctly.

Comment: Also, and much more importantly, `numFrames(1:10)` -> `numFrames >= 10`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist im looking for points showing and not if they are empty! they must show and the only way to check that I know is `isempty(points) == false`

Comment: @MadPhysicist this will check all numFrames individually from n to 10, so if it =5 it is true and that is not what I want. I want to check all 10 previous frames together if they shown points.

Comment: @UZIERSKI A) `~isempty(...)` is the same as `isempty(...) == false`, but clearer. B) In that case you need to store the frames/points from a previous iteration somewhere. Right now `numFrames` is a single integer and your code is broken.

Comment: Now you added an extra semicolon. Neither the while nor the if require a semicolon at the end. Have you tried actually running your code?

Comment: @MadPhysicist A) Yes you are right `~isempty()` works as well. B) i know but do not know how to do this. C) I run the code and it works if you set `numFrames(1:10) -> numFrames >= 10` as you said but I wanted to illustrate that I want range from `1:10` I will change it to make it more convenient.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it should work now (I'm using MatLab 2016). Without face detector it might be more suitable.

Comment: I am not familiar with the object returned by `detectMinEigenFeatures`. Do you know how to find the intersection of two return values? I.e., how do you know that the points it found were the same in two successive frames?

Comment: The method in this tutorial might be helpful for you [link](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/video-stabilization-using-point-feature-matching.html). But if you are trying to solve my problem do not worry about `detectMinEigenFeatures` as for my official code I have different function for actually calculating `Optical Flow` which I will use but it is extensive amount of code to paste it here, and there are multiple functions for it, therefore I simplified it using `detectMinEigenFeatures` as an example, because the output is similar although it is showing lines and not points.

Comment: @MadPhysicist can you have a look at this updated code and let me know why is this still shows not detected for the first 10 frames and the detected even tho there is no movement and optical flow is not displayed. How should I make it detect any movement appearing for maximum of 10 frames?

Answer (score 3):

If all you are trying to do is find out if any points have been found in each of the last 10 frames, you can do something like this:

```
vid = vision.VideoFileReader('MEXTest.mp4','ImageColorSpace','Intensity','VideoOutputDataType','uint8');

numFrames = 0;

frameList = {}
hasPoints = zeros(10, 1, 'logical')

while ~isDone(vid)
    frame = step(vid);
    points = detectMinEigenFeatures(frame);

    notEmpty = ~isempty(points)
    if numel(notEmpty) ~= 1, notEmpty = 1; end

    % Do the check for 10 frames before this step
    % if you want to exclude the current frame from the 10
    hasPoints = [hasPoints(2:end); notEmpty]

    % Stashing the frames may not be necessary, this
    % just shows how to build up a circular buffer
    if numFrames >= 10
        frameList = [frameList(2:end) frame]
    else
        frameList = [frameList frame]
    end

    % Count last frame now that it has been added
    numFrames = numFrames + 1;

    if numFrames >= 10 && all(hasPoints)
        disp('Detected')
    else
        disp('Not Detected')
    end
end
release(vid)
```

The circular buffer `frameList` will keep track of the last 10 frames. That step is not really crucial. What is crucial is `hasPoints` which stores a flag equal to `~isempty(points)` for each of the last 10 frames. If `all(hasPoints)` is true, than all of the last 10 frames detected a feature.

This solution is not super-efficient because it reallocates the accumulation arrays repeatedly, but it only does so for 10 frames using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1487071/2988730) solution for a circular buffer. You know what they say about premature optimization though.

Keep in mind that I do not check if the points are the ones you want in every case, just that the last 10 frames have some points detected. From your comments, it seems as though this is an acceptable interpretation.

Comment: It gives me error in line 14 - Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent. Can I move this `~isempty(points)` to the second if statement (adding another AND operator) rather than concatenating them? Will this give me the same output?

Comment: You have to concatenate them to keep adding it to the list, otherwise you will never accumulate info on the previous frames. What is `size(isempty(points))`?

Comment: What is the class?

Comment: i mean it is 1 1 if it is empty

Comment: the class is logical

Comment: Just checking. Updated based on what you said. I basically check if there is a single false value or not. This is a total hack, but since you will be using a different detection function anyway, that won't matter. This should serve as an adequate illustration of the concept.

Comment: still gives me this error at line 17 - Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent. (Can you concatenate matrices if they constantly change value?)

Comment: Oops you are absolutely right. I forgot I had made it into a column vector "to avoid confusion".

Comment: Fixed with semicolon: `hasPoints(2:end);`

Comment: @UZIERSKI If this works for you, please select the answer.

Comment: the function runs and works now, and I wish to put this as answered because you been very helpful, but it still gives not detected for first 10 frames and then its always detected. I don't know maybe I can send you my full project somewhere and you can check it yourself, if you want along with the video provided?

Comment: I updated the code so have a look it is still not detected for first 10 frames and then it is detected. This is the shortest version of the full program I could provide.

Comment: I set the bounty so the reward for your effort will be bigger. I would appropriate a lot if you could try my new code and test if there is no movement (lines) in the given video nothing is detected and if there is movement (lines) for all 10 frames it is detected and if its more than 10 again nothing is detected.

Comment: Have a look at `vision.OpticalFlow System object` at mathworks it has a list of properties that might be useful but I do not know which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked so much with videos - but a general procedure would be to store it in an array of structs. Call if frames, then you can initialize it with:

```
frames(10) = struct('prob1',0,'prob2',0,...,'probn',0);
```

where prob1, prob2,..., probn is the properties of the frame you want to save. Then every time you load a frame, you save the properties of that frame to a struct frame in the same manner.

```
frame = struct('prob1',val1,'prob2',val2,...,'probn',valn);
```

where val1, val2, ..., valn, be be everything, including the frame as a matrix. After this save it to the list

```
frames = [frames(2:end),frame];
```

then at every point in time you have the properties you need from the 10 previous frames, which you access by:

```
frames(2).prob2
```

which will give you the second property of the frame 8 frames ago. So it is just a minor change from what you already have, but (if I understood your question correctly) it should solve the problem.