# How to develop a FIFO Circular Buffer for analyzing real-time data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, buffer

I'm working on a project using the Polhemus Liberty system for real-time motion tracking. Recently, I have developed a GUI in Matlab's GUIDE to acquire the position and orientation of the attached sensors at a 240Hz sampling frequency. Also, I added an artificial neural network (ANN) to do some predictions on the kinematic parameters in real-time. However, after having the ANN's predictions I should do some data analysis on multiple dimension arrays. Without having the real-time criteria this particular data analysis could only be done by adding multiple nested loops because of the high dimensionality. The issue is that if I add FOR loops  to the method then the real-time (or close to real-time) criteria will definitely be harmed. In order to avoid the addition of the nested FOR loops I thought I could create a buffer (FIFO circular buffer) to temporarily store the predicted data and have the data analyzed. I have found a smart solution under the following link:

[Create a buffer matrix for continuous measurements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821637/create-a-buffer-matrix-for-continuous-measurements)

1) Buffer init.:

```
nBuffer = 10;  % You can set this to whatever number of time points
           %   you want to store data for
nSamples = 2;  % You can set this to the number of data values you
           %   need for each point in time
centroidBuffer = zeros(nSamples,nBuffer);  % Initialize the buffer to zeroes
```

2) Continuous looping, buffer usage:

```
keepLooping = true;
processTime = 0;
while keepLooping, 
% Capture your image
% Compute the centroid data and place it in the vector "centroidData"
centroidBuffer = [centroidBuffer(:,2:end) centroidData(:)];
processTime = processTime+1;
if (processTime == nBuffer),
 % Do whatever processing you want to do on centroidBuffer
processTime = 0;
end
% Choose to set keepLooping to false, if you want
end
```

In my understanding, the above solution works as a '1 frame/sec' method. So after capturing an image and defining its 'centroid data' only one column will be either removed or expanded in the buffer mechanism. This works quite well in that particular case. What would happen if the sampling rate is not 1 sample/sec but 240Hz. Given an infinite while loop the data loss will be increased without changing the parameters of the buffer.

Does somebody have an idea how to either modify the linked solution or to create a completely new one? In the buffer I should have 100 samples to analyze.

Let's have some brainstorming on it!
I'm opened to have some smart ideas.
Thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: It would be better if you inline the relevant portion of code from the other post, so people wouldn't have to dig so deep.

Comment: Why not! :D I've just updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

```
centroidBuffer = [centroidBuffer(:,2:end) centroidData(:)];
```

This is a nice and simple solution, but it is slow. Every time you add a new vector, matlab has to copy the whole old data except the first entry. It you think about real-time, this is not a good idea.

I just uploaded my solution for a fast circular buffer to

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47025-circvbuf-m

The main idea of this circular buffer is constant and fast performance
and avoiding copy operations when using the buffer in a program:

```
% create a circular vector buffer
    bufferSz = 1000;
    vectorLen= 7;
    cvbuf = circVBuf(int64(bufferSz),int64(vectorLen));

% fill buffer with 99 vectors
    vecs = zeros(99,vectorLen,'double');
    cvbuf.append(vecs);

% loop over lastly appended vectors of the circVBuf:
    new = cvbuf.new;
    lst = cvbuf.lst;
    for ix=new:lst
       vec(:) = cvbuf.raw(:,ix);
    end

% or direct array operation on lastly appended vectors in the buffer (no copy => fast)
    new = cvbuf.new;
    lst = cvbuf.lst;
    mean = mean(cvbuf.raw(3:7,new:lst));
```

Check the screenshot to see, that this circular buffer has advantages if the buffer is large, but the size of data to append each time is small as the performance of circVBuf does NOT depend on the buffer size, compared to a simple copy buffer.

The double buffering garanties a predictive time for an append depending on the data to append in any situation. In future this class shall give you a choice for double buffering yes or no - things will speedup, if you do not need the garantied time. 
[image]