# Creating a video buffer for temporally dependent real time processing function

Tags: matlab, video

We currently have some Matlab code that manipulates a video to magnify motion.
Traditionally, this is done with videos that have already been acquired.
However, we want to re-do it so that we can have two preview windows - one with an original live stream coming in through an attached camera and the second with the outputted processed video, all displaying in real time.

I understand that this requires video buffering (using a circular buffer?), however I'm not exactly sure how to create a buffer that stores a rolling second or two of video data that can then be used by the function to be processed and then displayed in realtime.

I have already set it up so that the entire script with record a second of video data then process it and then save it as an avi file, however how can I get about doing it in real time?

I was thinking that if I construct a while loop for a very short specified amount of time that records the video, processes it and then display it, that may work.

As you can see, I'm a complete beginner and any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821637/create-a-buffer-matrix-for-continuous-measurements [explanation video here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/05/08/implementing-a-simple-circular-buffer/)